# Converting a python object to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert this python object to a pandas dataframe. But it's saying that it's not 1-Dimensional so it cannot convert. It was originally a .mat file that I converted to a python list.
The list looks like this when printed:

```
{'__header__': b'MATLAB 5.0', '__version__': '1.0', '__globals__': [], 'val': array([[-20, -17,  -2, ..., -11,  -4, -11],
[-12,  -8,  -5, ...,  -9,  -9,  -9]], dtype=int16)}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

if you want to 2 columns

```
pd.DataFrame(data['val'].T)
```

Output:

```
0   1
0   -20 -12
1   -17 -8
2   -2  -5
3   -11 -9
4   -4  -9
5   -11 -9
```

else you can do

```
pd.DataFrame(data['val'])
```

Output :

```
0   1   2   3   4   5
0   -20 -17 -2  -11 -4  -11
1   -12 -8  -5  -9  -9  -9
```

Comment: Thank you @ShubhamShswat, this is what I was searching for.

Comment: @AdarshMishra depending on what you want to be part of your df, since if you just interested in arrays you can do this way

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this function:

[https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html]

Comment: Hi @salmanhammad this didnt work either. It's showing the same error.

Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional

Comment: I see. it cant sort the 'val' array which is a mat in one column. you will have to reshape 'val' array first to a one dim or save it in a different dataframe.